# Can't get AABB Collision to work properly

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx, collision-detection, aabb

This is the code I'm using to resolve collisions on the players left side. It works when I'm on the ground, but if I'm falling, it does not work.

```
public static boolean onWall(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2){

    if(rect1.x > rect2.x && rect1.x <= rect2.x + rect2.width && ((rect1.y > rect2.y && rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height) || rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y && rect1.y + rect1.height < rect2.y + rect2.height)){
        rect1.x = rect2.x + rect2.width;
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Do not post your solution as an edit into your question, instead post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry finally figured it out, heres my code just in case anyone else needs help

```
public static boolean yCollision(Rectangle p, ArrayList<Rectangle> a, Vector2 v){
    for(Rectangle r: a){
        if(p.y + v.y <= r.y + r.height && ((p.x > r.x && p.x < r.x + r.width) || (p.x + p.width > r.x && p.x + p.width < r.x + r.width)) && p.y > r.y + (r.height / 2)){
            p.y = r.y + r.height;
            return true;
        }
        if(v.y > 0){
            if(p.y + p.height + v.y > r.y && p.y + v.y + p.height < r.y + r.height && ((p.x > r.x && p.x < r.x + r.width) || (p.x + p.width > r.x && p.x + p.width < r.x + r.width)) && p.y > r.y){
                p.y = r.y - p.height;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static String xCollision(Rectangle p, ArrayList<Rectangle> a, Vector2 v){
    for(Rectangle r: a){
        if(p.x + v.x <= r.x + r.width && p.x + v.x >= r.x && ((p.y > r.y  && p.y < r.y + r.height) || (p.y + p.height > r.y && p.y + p.height < r.y + r.height))){
            p.x = r.x + r.width;
            return "left";
        }
        if(p.x + p.width + v.x >= r.x && p.x + p.width + v.x <= r.x + r.width && ((p.y > r.y  && p.y < r.y + r.height) || (p.y + p.height > r.y && p.y + p.height < r.y + r.height))){
            p.x = r.x - p.width;
            return "right";
        }
    }
    return "none";
}
```

Comment: This answer would be even better if it explained what you changed and why that solved the problem.